# Creating large txt file filled with arbitrary data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to create a single txt file in  MATLAB , which is e.g. 2GB large (not GiB for simplicity). It can contain arbitrary data. 
In Python (or C) it's possible to do it simply (Python 3.4 code):

```
path = r'D:\\file.txt' 
f = open(path, 'w') 
f.seek(2e9 - 1)
f.write('\x00')
f.close()
```

This approach (i.e. seeking past file end and writing a single NUL value) doesn't work in MATLAB R2007b, although this one works in MATLAB:

```
path = 'D:\file.txt';    
f = fopen(path, 'w'); % or 'W'    
fwrite(f, 0, 'uint8', 2e9 - 1);    
fclose(f);
```

The problem is that using MATLAB is almost 17 times slower than Python.... I didn't expect faster execution, but 17x is too much, 1 min <-> 17 min is hell of a difference.
Is there any faster way to do this in MATLAB?

Specs:

- OS: Windows
- MATLAB: R2007b
- File system: FAT32

Edit:
The same approach in MATLAB as in Python doesn't work, because fseek returns -1, probably it reaches EOF and doesn't like it. Here's the code for that:

```
path = 'D:\file.txt';    
f = fopen(path, 'w'); % or 'W'    
fseek(f, 2e9 -  1, 'bof') ;
fwrite(f, uint8(0));    
fclose(f);
```

Comment: R2007b is very old, did you not consider upgrading to a newer version?
Filewriting functions in MATLAB are e.g. dlmwrite, sprintf, table, fwrite etc. Lots of options to consider. I'm not familiar with Python, but I suspect there have been a lot of efficiency improvements in both MATLAB and Python over the past 7 years.

Comment: I'll definitely try it in newer version, but for now I'm stuck with this one. Also I read that fwrite is the fastest way to do it, but as you can see it's still quite slow. Also the python code is there only to serve as "pseudocode", it's very similar in C :)

Comment: You don't do the same thing in the two code snippets, so this begs the question: why do you expect to have comparable results?

Comment: Well as I mentioned, fseek method doesn't work in Matlab, it exits with code - 1

Comment: @LStarling, you didn't mention that...

Comment: @excaza I believe I did: "This approach doesn't work in MATLAB" :)

Comment: @LStarling which is unhelpfully vague. Nowhere in your question shows the approach you tried using `fseek` nor that it exits with code -1. Your unsuccessful attempts would be useful information to include in a question. Unfortunately we are not yet omniscient.

Comment: Hm....quite true, sorry for that, I'll add that there

Comment: @LStarling Which one of the following is working? `fseek(f, 2e6 - 1, 'bof')`, `fseek(f, 2e3 - 1, 'bof')`, `fseek(f, 1, 'bof')`?

Comment: Well... Neither :D if that's only because of Matlab version, then I can't do anything I guess, but if this is also happening in newer versions, the problem remains

Comment: @CST-Link @LStarling I think it might boil down to the implementation of `fseek`, if it's similar to C/C++ then I don't think it allows you to seek past the `eof`, throwing an error instead.

Comment: @LStarling I use R2012a, and has no issue creating the files. Do you have lots of files like this to create?

Comment: @CST-Link only a few, but I'm doing it for someone who doesn't have newer MATLAB, that's why I'm stuck with 2007b....but if you can create 2GB file in newer version in decent time , then I guess we can blaim old version for not working.... Either way thank you very much so far for fast responses :)

Comment: @excaza NTFS. Not sure if it matters either. I think you're right, it must be the underlying library function wrapped by the `fwrite` MATLAB function.

Comment: @CST-Link damn.... I meant I need only a few files in one batch, I don't know how many batches there will be. That's why I'm concerned about time, otherwise I would wait or did it in Python or C :)

Comment: @LStarling Do you have Python and MATLAB on the same machine? I changed the answer in case yes.

Comment: @CST-Link yes, matlab and python are on the same machine, I'll try your edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Try to do in MATLAB the same thing as in Python:</del>

```
tic;
path = 'D:\file.txt';    
f = fopen(path, 'W');
fseek(f, 2e9 - 1, 'eof'); %'Try with 2e8, 2e7...'
fwrite(f, uint8(0));
fclose(f);
toc;
```

(apparently seeking past file EOF doesn't work in R2007b)

Alternatively, execute the fast writing Python script from MATLAB:

```
cmd_template = 'python.exe C:\\PathToScript\\new_file.py "%s"'
system(sprintf(cmd_template, 'D:\file.txt'));
```

Of course, the "new_file.py" must accept at least one input arg, the new file name.

Comment: This only gives me a 1 line file in R2014b. It's very fast though, 0.001316 seconds! Woo!

Comment: @CST-Link executing python script in MATLAB works like a charm, although it's not actually MATLAB solution , is it? :D Either way, it works and you also mentioned in your answer it's old version problem...Thank you very much :) PS: \ is escape character in Python, so there should be \\ in path, I believe :)

Comment: @LStarling No problem. I feel your pain: sometimes I'm frustrated too by the limitations of the old versions, and the need to work with whatever is at hand. As for the double backslash issue, this should be fixed in both places. because backslash is escape char also for MATLAB's `sprintf`. Good point, correcting the code now.

Comment: @CST-Link I have to thank you again, because I was thinking about executing python script thanks to your answer and I got an idea that maybe there is a system command which does what I want...well....there is :D

Answer (score 0):

Hm...this hit me in the shower, it's of course platform dependend.

```
system('fsutil file createnew file.txt 2000000000');
```

I don't know why I didn't think of that sooner :D

Comment: That's nice. :-) And I think that R2007b is a far more limiting condition than a Win MATLAB installation, so every platform specific thing is something to be considered. You can use the functions `ver` and `computer` to fall back graciously from the initial assumptions about the MATLAB version and the operating system.